# Are there nice Lie groups $G$ and $H$ such that $G \times G \times G / \mathbb Z_3 \cong H?$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, group-isomorphism

Are there nice Lie groups $G$ and $H$ such that
$$G \times G \times G /\mathbb Z_3 \cong H?$$

I'm looking for analogies to $SO(3)\times SO(3) /\mathbb Z_2 \cong SO(4)$, which has an interpretation in that left- and right-isoclinic rotations provide a double cover of $SO(4)$.

I can see solutions that aren't particularly 'nice'; eg for any $G$ with a $3$-element normal subgroups $\mathbb Z_3 \sim N \unlhd G$ we could define $H = (G/\mathbb Z_3) \times G \times G$. (An example would be $G = U(1), N = \left\{1, e^{\tfrac 23\pi i}, e^{\tfrac 43\pi i}\right\}$.)

I'm hoping there are constructions that preserve a symmetry between the $3$ copies of $G$.

Comment: By $\sim$, do you mean an isomorphism?

Comment: Also, please do not use titles that are entirely $\rm\LaTeX$.

Comment: Yes, by ~ I meant 'is isomorphic to'

Comment: The "nicest" example I know is $S^1\times S^1\times S^1/ \mathbb{Z}_3\cong S^1\times S^1\times S^1$.  (The particular embedding of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ into $S^1\times S^1\times S^1$ is irrelevant.)

Comment: You are using $\setminus$ (`\setminus`), which is the set theoretic difference operator (that is, $A\setminus B=\{a\in A\mid a\notin B\}$). If you mean quotient, use `/`; and you can use `\cong` to get $\cong$, the usual symbol for isomorphism.